# INNER JOIN with DJANGO framework

Tags: python, sql, django

Two weeks I try to make a JOIN with django

```html
class Groupe(models.Model):
 nomgroupe = models.CharField(max_length=50)

 def __str__(self):
  return self.nomgroupe

class Album(models.Model):
 code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 nomgroupe = models.ForeignKey(Groupe, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
 nomalbum = models.CharField(max_length=100)

 def __str__(self):
  return self.nomalbum
```

I would like to search the albums of several groups. For example starting with "iron"
In SQL:

```html
SELECT * FROM MP3_album INNER JOIN MP3_groupe ON MP3_album.nomgroupe_id = MP3_groupe.id WHERE MP3_groupe.nomgroupe LIKE '%iron%';
```

But with DJANGO I only get there with a hard code to read

can you help me?

ps: Excuse me my english please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter and [contains/icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#contains):

```
Album.objects.filter(nomgroupe__nomgroupe__contains='iron')
```